# PHP: Keep Only Next and Previous Paginator Links

Tags: php, pagination

I have this example pagination code that I've been working on that I found on another site. I finally have functioning with my database and paging my data. However, I don't want the script to list the number of page and only want to display the "next" and "previous" pagination links. I can't figure it out but maybe one of you guys can:

```
<?php
    include('sqlconnect.php');
    include('getdata.php');
    mysql_select_db("barter") or die(mysql_error());

        // include your code to connect to DB.

    $tbl_name="posts";      //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "fp2.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 3;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */






// Set session variables

$City = $_GET['City'];



$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE City = \"$City\" LIMIT $start, $limit";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&City=$City\"><img style=\"width:50px; height:50px; clear:all; position:fixed; bottom:30%; right:10;\"src=\"Images/leftarrow.jpg\" /></a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";   

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&City=$City\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&City=$City\">$lastpage</a>";        
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&City=$City\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&City=$City\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&City=$City\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&City=$City\">$lastpage</a>";        
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&City=$City\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&City=$City\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next&City=$City\"><img style=\"width:50px; height:50px; clear:all; position:fixed; bottom:40%; right:10;\"src=\"Images/uparrow.jpg\" /></a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty but should do the job, comment all the `//pages` part of your code :

```
<?php
    include('sqlconnect.php');
    include('getdata.php');
    mysql_select_db("barter") or die(mysql_error());

        // include your code to connect to DB.

    $tbl_name="posts";      //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "fp2.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 3;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */






// Set session variables

$City = $_GET['City'];



$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE City = \"$City\" LIMIT $start, $limit";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&City=$City\"><img style=\"width:50px; height:50px; clear:all; position:fixed; bottom:30%; right:10;\"src=\"Images/leftarrow.jpg\" /></a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";   

        //pages 
        /*
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&City=$City\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&City=$City\">$lastpage</a>";        
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&City=$City\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&City=$City\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&City=$City\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&City=$City\">$lastpage</a>";        
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&City=$City\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&City=$City\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&City=$City\">$counter</a>";                  
                }
            }
        }
        */

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next&City=$City\"><img style=\"width:50px; height:50px; clear:all; position:fixed; bottom:40%; right:10;\"src=\"Images/uparrow.jpg\" /></a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
```